# IIS not serving static content (css/js/images, etc) 404

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

I have done this 1 million times....

- Create project (in this case it's empty web application using only
  HTML files).
- Edit hosts file to allow custom URL (local.xxx-xxx.com)
- Create IIS website and app pool to point to local.xxx-xxx.com and
  choose start directory.
- Edit permissions on root folder to allow IIS_IUSRS and NETWORK
  SERVICE to be able to access files.

I've gone into IIS to check if "Static Content" checkbox was checked in "Windows Features", and it is.

What am I not seeing?

[image]

Also, for example, when I browse to "http://local.xxx-xxx.com/source/sass/main.min.css" I get:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

> IIS will not return file types that are not added to the
>    element or that have mappings in the 
>   element by default. This behavior prevents unauthorized access to
>   files that do not have mappings in the IIS 7 configuration settings.

[image]

[image]

The  element of the  element adds a unique MIME type to the collection of static content types. Each  entry must consist of two parts:

> A unique file name extension that is specified by the fileExtension
>   attribute, for example, ".txt", ".png", etc. A MIME type for the file
>   name extension that is specified by the mimeType attribute, for
>   example, "text/plain", "image/jpg", etc.

[Reference](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap)

Comment: text/css is in my MIME types though - however, mine has "Local" as the entry type, and I do not see where I can change it to "Inherited".

Comment: Inherited it means the site inherits this MIME type from the server level configuration, so should not be your problem, sorry

Answer (score -1):

Typical mistake: you create an application on IIS instead of a web site.

`http://localhost/ExampleApp`

The routes in HTML are absolute:

`http://localhost/css/main.css`

It is not found, because it is located here:

`http://localhost/ExampleApp/css/main.css`